# Rstudio - software not opening

Tags: r, rstudio, startup

Rstudio start up issue: For the past couple of days i have been attempting to overcome the R start up issue i am facing. After R crashed, it now will not let me open showing the below failure report.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.03.1+446 "Cherry Blossom " (6e31ffc3, 2023-05-09) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.1+446 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477.

Error output:

```
[23792:24860:20230526,184556.367:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specifi,ed. (3)
,[23792:24860:20230526,184601.244:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/BOSM8882/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-bosm8882.log*

```
2023-05-24T09:36:57.109168Z [rsession-bosm8882] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\elsbeth-geranium\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\elsbeth-geranium\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161
2023-05-24T09:36:57.109168Z [rsession-bosm8882] ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\elsbeth-geranium\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\elsbeth-geranium\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161
```

I have attempted to un-install and re-install baseline R and Rstudio multiple times, I have restarted my laptop and searched online for an answer and am struggling to overcome this issue.